Can't open forms from sln project from GitLab
I had to restore a sln project from GitLab and i can't open some forms in the Designer.
I had several types of error:

The connection to the server has been lost (in a popup message box)
Object not set to an instance + at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.Sessions.InitializeRootComponentHandler.HandleRequest(InitializeRootComponentRequest request) at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.RequestHandler`2.Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.IRequestHandler.HandleRequest(Request reques (in the designer error windows)
"Exception of type "System.Exception" has been thrown"

Here what i've done to get there:

get the zip with source code from GitLab
unzip it (on local path)
open the project with Visual Studio

What i've tried so far:

reinstall Visual Studio Community
clean and rebuild the solution (which is successful)
Delete /obj and /bin directory...

VS runs with admin privileges.
I guess there is some errors somewhere but i can't find where because of the lack of verbosity. Any idea to point out that problem source(s)?
